# Populate Wix Calendar From Database

Tags: database, calendar, velo, event-calendar

I have a schedule event calendar in Wix.
I need to process data in it, count and show how many events/records weekly, monthly and yearly.

I believe the best way is storing data in database. Put into calendar and show the report manually.

I could not do these with Calendars in the Wix Market. Can you help me  please??

I tried: - Google Calendar - Wix Event Calendar - Html embedded Team Up Calendar - Infuse Calendar - Wix Event Reservation..

In my form I have: -Name & Surname -Date & Time - Notes

I tried to relate calendar & database & form via $w("#calendar") but this just gave me "collapsed, hidden, global,...src" etc. So I was unable to access calendar's dataset. src" etc.

Comment: Hi. Please share what you already tried so we can have a look.

Comment: Hi. Actually I could not do anything that works. Db is not being related to calendar. There is no option about that

Comment: Doesnt matter if it works, show it, so we can have a look why it doesnt work. Thats what we do here ;)

Comment: Oh okay than. Thanks :) I am gonna post the images in a minute

Comment: Dont post images please, integrate your code properly into the post. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on how to properly do that.

Comment: Actually I can just tell  what I tried. 
I added:
- Google Calendar
- Wix Event Calendar
- Html embedded Team Up Calendar
- Hotel Reservation
- Wix Event Reservation..

In my form I have:  
- Person
- Date & Time
- Notes

I tried to relate calendar & database & form via $w("#calendar") but this just gave me "collapsed, hidden, global,... src" etc. I